# String split limiters

Tags: java, regex, split

I am new to Java. There is a string "a + b - c * d / e", and I want to get a ,b,c,d,e

But it fails (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException)

```
    String str = "a + b - c * d / e";
    String [] value = str.split("+-*/");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Split your input according to the below regex.

```
String str = "a + b - c * d / e";
String[] value = str.split("\\s*[-+*/]\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

`\\s*` matches zero or more space. `[-+*/]` matches a single character from the given list. I suggest you to put `-` at the start or at the end of the character class because `-` at the middle of character class sometimes would act like a range operator.

**Update:**

Try this if you want the program to return only the operator.

```
    String str = "1.23 + 3 - 5 * 4 / 5.7";
    String[] value = str.split("\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: value){
        if(!s.equals("")) list.add(s);
    }
   System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[+, -, *, /]
```

Comment: It works. Where do I find the regex tutorial for string.split ?

Comment: This http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best site for learning regexes. Not only for splitting, regex would also do the job of matching.

Comment: Thanks ! If i want to split the integer or double value in "1.23 + 3 - 5 * 4 / 5.7"   -> +, - , * , /

Comment: use the same regex, it would return `[1.23, 3, 5, 4, 5.7]`

Comment: Sorry, it should split "1.23 + 3 - 5 * 4 / 5.7" -> +, - , * , /

Comment: did you want only operators?

Comment: Yes, extract operators.

Comment: @peterho split your input according to this `"\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*"` regex.

Comment: Get 5 operators. The first one is empty "", "+", "-","*", "/"